# Row Background Color GtkTreeView Widget

Tags: c++, gtk, gtkmm, gtktreeview

I'm attempting to color disabled rows in a gtk tree view widget a light gray color.  From what I've read, I'm supposed to set the background-gdk property of the corresponding cellrenderer and bind it to a model column.  This sort of works.

```
Gtk::CellRendererText* textRenderer = manage(new Gtk::CellRendererText());
textRenderer->property_editable() = false;
Gtk::TreeViewColumn *col = manage(new Gtk::TreeViewColumn("Column1", *textRenderer));
col->add_attribute(*textRenderer, "background-gdk", m_treeview_columns.m_back_color);
my_treeview.append_column(*col);

Gtk::TreeModel::Row row;
for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_ROWS; iLane++){
   row = *(treeview_liststore->append());
   row[m_workListColumns.m_back_color] = Gdk::Color("#CCCCCC");
}
```

[image]

In the end though, I get only the cells colored properly.  BUT I also get an ugly white-space in between the cells.  Does anyone know of a way to fix this or a better way to achieve the effect I'm after?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you set the background of the row to match the cell background or set the bakground of the tree view all together ? Or maybe the cell with cell-background-gdk ?

Comment: Thanks @ivo s, I was using the wrong property, I needed "cell-background-gdk" and not "background-gdk".  Thanks for the help.