# GtkTreeView alternate row color

Tags: c++, css, glade, gtkmm

I can't set the alternate row color of a TreeView, I don't know why doesn't works.

This the code

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(BaseObjectType* cobject, const Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder>& refGlade) :
    Gtk::ApplicationWindow(cobject), refBuilder(refGlade){

    Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::CssProvider> cssProvider = Gtk::CssProvider::create();
    cssProvider->load_from_path("style.css");
    Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::StyleContext> styleContext = Gtk::StyleContext::create();
    Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::Screen> screen = Gdk::Screen::get_default();
    styleContext->add_provider_for_screen(screen, cssProvider, GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION);


    const char* user = "user";
    const char* passwd = "passwd";
    const char* database = "dbname";
    const char* dbhost = "192.168.1.5";

    connection = mysql_init(NULL);

    mysql_real_connect(connection, dbhost, user, passwd, database, 3307, NULL, 0);

    refBuilder->get_widget("m_TreeView1", m_TreeView1);


    m_refTreeModel = Gtk::ListStore::create(m_Columns);
    m_TreeView1->set_model(m_refTreeModel);

    /*Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::StyleContext> context = m_TreeView1->get_style_context();
context->add_class("treeview");
*/

    Affitto* affitti = new Affitto(connection);
    MYSQL_RES* res = affitti->getAll();
    MYSQL_ROW riga;
    Gtk::TreeModel::Row row;

    while ((riga = mysql_fetch_row(res))) 
    {

        row = *(m_refTreeModel->append());
        row[m_Columns.m_col_inqid] = std::stoi(riga[0]);
        row[m_Columns.m_col_cognomenome] = riga[1];
        row[m_Columns.m_col_stabile] = riga[2];
        row[m_Columns.m_col_mese] = std::stoi(riga[3]);
        row[m_Columns.m_col_anno] = std::stoi(riga[4]);
        row[m_Columns.m_col_posteggiopagato] = std::stod(riga[5]);
        row[m_Columns.m_col_affittopagato] = std::stod(riga[6]);
        row[m_Columns.m_col_riscaldamentopagato] = std::stod(riga[7]);
        row[m_Columns.m_col_pagatoil] = riga[8];
        row[m_Columns.m_col_stato] = riga[9];
        row[m_Columns.m_col_osservazioni] = riga[10];
        row[m_Columns.m_col_traslocato] = riga[11];
        row[m_Columns.m_col_diversi] = std::stod(riga[12]);
        row[m_Columns.m_col_affitto] = std::stod(riga[13]);
        row[m_Columns.m_col_posteggio] = std::stod(riga[14]);
        row[m_Columns.m_col_riscaldamento] = std::stod(riga[15]);

    }

    m_TreeView1->append_column("InqID", m_Columns.m_col_inqid);
    m_TreeView1->append_column("Cognome e nome", m_Columns.m_col_cognomenome);
    //m_TreeView1->get_column(1)->set_expand(true);
    m_TreeView1->append_column("Stabile", m_Columns.m_col_stabile);
    m_TreeView1->append_column("Mese", m_Columns.m_col_mese);
    m_TreeView1->append_column("Anno", m_Columns.m_col_anno);
    m_TreeView1->append_column("Posteggio pagato", m_Columns.m_col_posteggiopagato);
    m_TreeView1->append_column("Affitto pagato", m_Columns.m_col_affittopagato);
    m_TreeView1->append_column("Riscaldamento pagato", m_Columns.m_col_riscaldamentopagato);
    m_TreeView1->append_column("Pagato il", m_Columns.m_col_pagatoil);
    m_TreeView1->append_column("Stato", m_Columns.m_col_stato);
    m_TreeView1->append_column("Osservazioni", m_Columns.m_col_osservazioni);
    m_TreeView1->append_column("Traslocato", m_Columns.m_col_traslocato);
    m_TreeView1->append_column("Diversi", m_Columns.m_col_diversi);
    m_TreeView1->append_column("Affitto", m_Columns.m_col_affitto);
    m_TreeView1->append_column("Posteggio", m_Columns.m_col_posteggio);
    m_TreeView1->append_column("Riscaldamento", m_Columns.m_col_riscaldamento);




    mysql_free_result(res);
    mysql_close(connection);



}
```

And this the css, that is correctly loaded. I set the style class of the TreeView (treeview) in glade file.

```
.treeview row:nth-child(even) 
{ 
    background-color: #ff0000; 
}
.treeview row:nth-child(odd)
{
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

What's wrong? I tried too to set the style class by code (commented rows) but does't change. 
Thanks in advance for an help!

***update***

I put my updated code, what's I'm wrong?

```
Gtk::CellRendererText* textRenderer = manage(new Gtk::CellRendererText());
    textRenderer->property_editable() = false;
    Gtk::TreeViewColumn *col = manage(new Gtk::TreeViewColumn("InqId", *textRenderer));
    col->add_attribute(*textRenderer, "cell-background-rgba", m_Columns.m_col_inqid);
    m_TreeView1->append_column(*col);
while ((riga = mysql_fetch_row(res))) 
    {

        row = *(m_refTreeModel->append());
        row[m_Columns.m_col_inqid] = std::stoi(riga[0]);

        row[m_Columns.m_col_inqid] = Gdk::Color("#CCCCCC");

    }
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: It's possible that this is a bug?

Comment: .treeview .row:nth-child(even) _ I think you missed a dot(.) before row, as css does not acknowledge a row as an element by default.

Comment: thanks for the reply but it doesn't works

Comment: Can you provided the html structure of this view that is loaded in the browser, that could help us get a solution.

Comment: this is not an html page...it's a gtk application. What do you mean?

Comment: https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTreeView.html#GtkTreeView--s-odd-row-color

Comment: Following the documentation, there is already a standard properrty for this . Have a look  in the folllowing loink.

Comment: the odd-row-color style property is read-only. I want to set it...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the background color of a row you can use

`cell-background-gdk`

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkCellRenderer.html#GtkCellRenderer--cell-background-gdk)

Comment: thanks but I can't understand how to use it. I can set the background color of a column, not of a complete row. can you show me an example please? thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1):

Somebody else had already the same problem:

Probably you could do your a function where you grab each cell of a row and use
the already mentioned function or do it on cell creation as here:

[Row Background Color GtkTreeView Widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196854/row-background-color-gtktreeview-widget)

Watch out, he just used the wrong function for the color:

> Thanks @ivo s, I was using the wrong property, I needed
>   "cell-background-gdk" and not "background-gdk". Thanks for the help.

Use ***cell-background-rgba*** function instead of before mentioned cell-background-gdk cause **it is deprecated** and will be removed sooner or later.

Comment: I already saw this discussion...but I can't reproduce it...I update now my first post with what I'm doing, if you can help me to watch what's I'm wrong I thanks you very much

Answer (score 1):

so, now it works...this is the complete code in case of somebody have the same problem.
Thanks a lot for those help me!

the model:

```
class MainWindow : public Gtk::ApplicationWindow
{
    public:    
        MainWindow(BaseObjectType* cobject, const Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder>& refGlade);
        virtual ~MainWindow();
        MYSQL* connection;
    protected:
        Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder> refBuilder;


        class ModelColumns : public Gtk::TreeModel::ColumnRecord
        {
            public:

            ModelColumns()
            { 
                add(m_col_inqid);
                add(m_col_cognomenome);
                add(m_col_stabile);
                add(m_col_mese);
                add(m_col_anno);
                add(m_col_posteggiopagato);
                add(m_col_affittopagato);
                add(m_col_riscaldamentopagato);
                add(m_col_pagatoil);
                add(m_col_stato);
                add(m_col_osservazioni);
                add(m_col_traslocato);
                add(m_col_diversi);
                add(m_col_affitto);
                add(m_col_posteggio);
                add(m_col_riscaldamento);
                add(m_coloreriga);
            }


            Gtk::TreeModelColumn<int> m_col_inqid;
            Gtk::TreeModelColumn<std::string> m_col_cognomenome;
            Gtk::TreeModelColumn<std::string> m_col_stabile;
            Gtk::TreeModelColumn<int> m_col_mese;
            Gtk::TreeModelColumn<int> m_col_anno;
            Gtk::TreeModelColumn<double> m_col_posteggiopagato;
            Gtk::TreeModelColumn<double> m_col_affittopagato;
            Gtk::TreeModelColumn<double> m_col_riscaldamentopagato;
            Gtk::TreeModelColumn<std::string> m_col_pagatoil;
            Gtk::TreeModelColumn<std::string> m_col_stato;
            Gtk::TreeModelColumn<std::string> m_col_osservazioni;
            Gtk::TreeModelColumn<std::string> m_col_traslocato;
            Gtk::TreeModelColumn<double> m_col_diversi;
            Gtk::TreeModelColumn<double> m_col_affitto;
            Gtk::TreeModelColumn<double> m_col_posteggio;
            Gtk::TreeModelColumn<double> m_col_riscaldamento;
            Gtk::TreeModelColumn<Gdk::RGBA> m_coloreriga;

        };

        ModelColumns m_Columns;
        Gtk::TreeView* m_TreeView1;
        Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::ListStore> m_refTreeModel;


};
```

the main:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(BaseObjectType* cobject, const Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder>& refGlade) :
    Gtk::ApplicationWindow(cobject), refBuilder(refGlade){

    Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::CssProvider> cssProvider = Gtk::CssProvider::create();
    cssProvider->load_from_path("style.css");
    //cssProvider->load_from_data(cssProvider, ".treeview row:nth-child(even){  background-color: #ff0000; } .treeview row:nth-child(odd){ background-color: #000000; }", -1, NULL);
    Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::StyleContext> styleContext = Gtk::StyleContext::create();
    Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::Screen> screen = Gdk::Screen::get_default();
    styleContext->add_provider_for_screen(screen, cssProvider, GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION);


    const char* user = "root";
    const char* passwd = "";
    const char* database = "";
    const char* dbhost = "192.168.1.5";

    connection = mysql_init(NULL);

    mysql_real_connect(connection, dbhost, user, passwd, database, 3307, NULL, 0);

    refBuilder->get_widget("m_TreeView1", m_TreeView1);

    //m_Button_Quit.signal_clicked().connect( sigc::mem_fun(*this, &MainWindow::on_button_quit) );

    m_refTreeModel = Gtk::ListStore::create(m_Columns);
    m_TreeView1->set_model(m_refTreeModel);
Affitto* affitti = new Affitto(connection);    
    MYSQL_RES* res = affitti->getAll();
    MYSQL_ROW riga;
    Gtk::TreeModel::Row row;
Gtk::CellRendererText* textRenderer = manage(new Gtk::CellRendererText());
    Gtk::TreeViewColumn *col = manage(new Gtk::TreeViewColumn("InqId", *textRenderer));
    col->add_attribute(*textRenderer, "cell-background-rgba", m_Columns.m_coloreriga);
    m_TreeView1->append_column(*col);

    textRenderer = manage(new Gtk::CellRendererText());
    col = manage(new Gtk::TreeViewColumn("Cognome e nome", *textRenderer));
    col->add_attribute(*textRenderer, "cell-background-rgba", m_Columns.m_coloreriga);
    m_TreeView1->append_column(*col);
m_TreeView1->append_column("Stabile", m_Columns.m_col_stabile);
    m_TreeView1->append_column("Mese", m_Columns.m_col_mese);
    m_TreeView1->append_column("Anno", m_Columns.m_col_anno);
    m_TreeView1->append_column("Posteggio pagato", m_Columns.m_col_posteggiopagato);
    m_TreeView1->append_column("Affitto pagato", m_Columns.m_col_affittopagato);
    m_TreeView1->append_column("Riscaldamento pagato", m_Columns.m_col_riscaldamentopagato);
    m_TreeView1->append_column("Pagato il", m_Columns.m_col_pagatoil);
    m_TreeView1->append_column("Stato", m_Columns.m_col_stato);
    m_TreeView1->append_column("Osservazioni", m_Columns.m_col_osservazioni);
    m_TreeView1->append_column("Traslocato", m_Columns.m_col_traslocato);
    m_TreeView1->append_column("Diversi", m_Columns.m_col_diversi);
    m_TreeView1->append_column("Affitto", m_Columns.m_col_affitto);
    m_TreeView1->append_column("Posteggio", m_Columns.m_col_posteggio);
    m_TreeView1->append_column("Riscaldamento", m_Columns.m_col_riscaldamento);

 int i=0;
    while ((riga = mysql_fetch_row(res))) 
    {

        row = *(m_refTreeModel->append());
        row[m_Columns.m_col_inqid] = std::stoi(riga[0]);
        row[m_Columns.m_col_cognomenome] = riga[1];
        row[m_Columns.m_col_stabile] = riga[2];
        row[m_Columns.m_col_mese] = std::stoi(riga[3]);
        row[m_Columns.m_col_anno] = std::stoi(riga[4]);
        row[m_Columns.m_col_posteggiopagato] = std::stod(riga[5]);
        row[m_Columns.m_col_affittopagato] = std::stod(riga[6]);
        row[m_Columns.m_col_riscaldamentopagato] = std::stod(riga[7]);
        row[m_Columns.m_col_pagatoil] = riga[8];
        row[m_Columns.m_col_stato] = riga[9];
        row[m_Columns.m_col_osservazioni] = riga[10];
        row[m_Columns.m_col_traslocato] = riga[11];
        row[m_Columns.m_col_diversi] = std::stod(riga[12]);
        row[m_Columns.m_col_affitto] = std::stod(riga[13]);
        row[m_Columns.m_col_posteggio] = std::stod(riga[14]);
        row[m_Columns.m_col_riscaldamento] = std::stod(riga[15]);

        if(i%2 == 0)
            row[m_Columns.m_coloreriga] = Gdk::RGBA("#ff0000");
        else
            row[m_Columns.m_coloreriga] = Gdk::RGBA("#cccccc");
        i++;        
    }





    mysql_free_result(res);
    mysql_close(connection);



}
```

Comment: Glad you did it. Congrats :)